# Dart For Loop is exiting before async function is completed

Tags: asynchronous, networking, flutter, dart

I am uploading images via multipart request one at a time to the server. Each time I send an image I am listening to the response for a success message.

If the returned `JSON["status"] == "Success"`, I update my local database accordingly to show that that particular image is synced. Once that image is updated locally, I increment a successes counter by 1.

At the end of the for loop in `insertImageApi`, I return a success message, including the number on images successfully uploaded.

I am successfully uploading all of the images to the server, but without my hack, the function is returning one less than expected. (ex. 5 out of 6)

I have tried including a 3-second delay to provide time to the function to add the last success increment, but that does not work.

Currently, I have a ternary operator in the return statement to return 0 if successes are == 0, otherwise, return successes + 1 to compensate for the last missed increment.

I have even tried incrementing successes before the `UpdateImageDbApi` asynchronous function. I am not really sure how I am missing this last increment. I do not see how I could eject from this for loop too soon, as I have await functions everywhere...

```dart
_handleApiResponse(var response, SafeguardImage image) async {
    var decodedResponse = json.decode(response);

    if (decodedResponse["status"] == "Success") {
      image.isSynced = 1;
      try {
        successes++; //HACK
        await UpdateImageDbApi().updateImage(image);

      } catch (e) {
        print('failed to update image row in db: ' + e.toString());
      }
    } else if (decodedResponse["status"] == "error") {
      try {
        SafeguardOrder order =
            await QueryOrderDbApi().queryOrder(image.orderId);
        order.isSyncable = 0;
        try {
          var result = await UpdateOrderDbApi().updateOrder(order);
          print("set order #${order.orderId} syncable to 0. result =" +
              result.toString());
        } catch (e) {
          print('unable to update order #${order.orderId} on db: ' +
              e.toString());
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("unable to query database for images order id: " + e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> insertImageAPI(
      List<SafeguardImage> images) async {

    var start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    for (var image in images) {
      print(image.imageUrl);

      http.MultipartRequest request = await _createMultipartRequest(image);
      print(request.toString());
      try {
        var response = await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 20));
        response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(
          (response) async {
            print(response.toString());
            await _handleApiResponse(response, image);
          },
        );
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        return {
          "error":
              "there was a network error. please try again when you have service"
        };
      }
    }
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)); //HACK
    var end = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    double duration = (end - start) / 1000;
    print(
        "post images complete: $successes sent. \n it took $duration seconds");
    return {
      "successes": successes == 0 ? 0 : successes + 1, //HACK
      "total_attempted": images.length,
      "duration": duration
    };
  }
```

I have marked the three hacks with comments.

Comment: `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));` does nothing - i have no idea how it could help you - try for example paste it: `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => print('delay1'));
  print('1');
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => print('delay2'));
  print('2');` into https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and see the output

Comment: thank you, I was thinking it would maybe delay the rest of the code for three seconds, so the last incrementation could take place before the entire function could return. but that is not working